# Sending JSON Data to MongDB via Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I currently have a JSON object and I'm having trouble persisting it to a mongoDB database via mongoose. There are two main questions I have.

1. Is my model setup correctly for the JSON object I have below? I've never used subdocuments before, so this is a first.
2. I keep getting an error when I try to persist the data (error: "object is not a function").  What am I doing wrong?

All code is below.

Here is how I've setup mongoose.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/yjs');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'mongodb connection error:'));

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var resultsSchema = new Schema({
    jobtitle: String,
    company: String,
    city: String,
    state: String,
    country: String,
    formattedLocation: String,
    source: String,
    date: String,
    snippet: String,
    url: String,
    onmousedown: String,
    jobkey: String,
    sponsored: Boolean,
    expired: Boolean,
    indeedApply: Boolean,
    formattedLocationFull: String,
    formattedRelativeTime: String
});

var jobSchema = new Schema({
    version: Number,
    query: String,
    location: String,
    dupefilter: Boolean,
    highlight: Boolean,
    radius: Number,
    start: Number,
    end: Number,
    totalResults: Number,
    pageNumber: Number,
    results: [resultsSchema]

});


var Jobs = mongoose.model('Jobs', jobSchema);

module.exports = {
    Jobs: Jobs
}
```

This is my JSON object:

```
{
  version: 2,
  query: "javascript $19,900-$20,900",
  location: "New York, NY",
  dupefilter: true,
  highlight: true,
  radius: 25,
  start: 1,
  end: 3,
  totalResults: 3,
  pageNumber: 0,
  results: [
    {
      jobtitle: "Web Application Developer",
      company: "Sogeti",
      city: "New York",
      state: "NY",
      country: "US",
      formattedLocation: "New York, NY",
      source: "Sogeti",
      date: "Sat, 15 Nov 2014 08:50:24 GMT",
      snippet: "Roles/ Responsibility/ Qualifications: Position Location: Raritan, New Jersey Sogeti is a leading provider of technology and software testing, specializing...",
      url: "http://www.indeed.com/viewjob?jk=5c3af4fc30704f52&qd=PgQusJx_gGiiAmACeKxgepvuLa6C1I07uk43fDZ3DSq8GvDGPvLAOvUmXryxs9bezoA6A_gJOaAYR60u2fV5hFgosDLOUjUrxWWMfxXcFW0txtBb9O5egndMhGuvOU46RMGL25yEMtQuUuTH37UmVA&indpubnum=9222093808317380&atk=19g75527l0np13ao",
      onmousedown: "indeed_clk(this, '2276');",
      jobkey: "5c3af4fc30704f52",
      sponsored: false,
      expired: false,
      indeedApply: false,
      formattedLocationFull: "New York, NY",
      formattedRelativeTime: "30+ days ago"
    },
    {
      jobtitle: "Interactive Designer – New York",
      company: "Unruly Ltd",
      city: "New York",
      state: "NY",
      country: "US",
      formattedLocation: "New York, NY",
      source: "Unruly Ltd",
      date: "Fri, 28 Nov 2014 00:05:17 GMT",
      snippet: "WANTED: Positioned at the intersect of the three fastest-growing trends in digital advertising – programmatic, video and mobile – Unruly is a high-growth tech",
      url: "http://www.indeed.com/viewjob?jk=98f978c3e33061d1&qd=PgQusJx_gGiiAmACeKxgepvuLa6C1I07uk43fDZ3DSq8GvDGPvLAOvUmXryxs9bezoA6A_gJOaAYR60u2fV5hFgosDLOUjUrxWWMfxXcFW0txtBb9O5egndMhGuvOU46RMGL25yEMtQuUuTH37UmVA&indpubnum=9222093808317380&atk=19g75527l0np13ao",
      onmousedown: "indeed_clk(this, '2276');",
      jobkey: "98f978c3e33061d1",
      sponsored: false,
      expired: false,
      indeedApply: true,
      formattedLocationFull: "New York, NY",
      formattedRelativeTime: "30+ days ago"
    },
    {
      jobtitle: "Java Angular JS Developer",
      company: "UST Global",
      city: "Edison",
      state: "NJ",
      country: "US",
      formattedLocation: "Edison, NJ",
      source: "Dice",
      date: "Wed, 18 Feb 2015 14:06:16 GMT",
      snippet: "Rakesh.Sasidharanust-global.com <b>Javascript</b>, Angular JS, JQuery, Ext. Java Angular JS Developer 5 years experience in Java and web development Should have...",
      url: "http://www.indeed.com/viewjob?jk=f347ca5dc7439231&qd=PgQusJx_gGiiAmACeKxgepvuLa6C1I07uk43fDZ3DSq8GvDGPvLAOvUmXryxs9bezoA6A_gJOaAYR60u2fV5hFgosDLOUjUrxWWMfxXcFW0txtBb9O5egndMhGuvOU46RMGL25yEMtQuUuTH37UmVA&indpubnum=9222093808317380&atk=19g75527l0np13ao",
      onmousedown: "indeed_clk(this, '2276');",
      jobkey: "f347ca5dc7439231",
      sponsored: false,
      expired: false,
      indeedApply: false,
      formattedLocationFull: "Edison, NJ 08817",
      formattedRelativeTime: "22 days ago"
    }
  ]
}
```

How I'm trying to persist data:

```
var job = new Jobs(json_object);

Jobs.create(json_object, function (err, job) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);

    return job();
});
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!  And sorry about the formatting of the JSON object, I can't get it to stay as code when I change the formatting. It's basically an object, with one of the key values being an array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

```
  models.Jobs.create(json_object, function (err) {
        if (err) {return handleError(err);

        } else {
            console.log('data collected')
        }

    })
```

The above code fixed the issue.  Also seems like the subdocuments are working correctly. I completely glanced over what the module I was requiring.